# <img src=""> Isn't accepting image path

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, path, paperclip

I have an image in my `app/assets/images/` folder called "Flower.jpg". `<%=image_tag("Flower.jpg")%>` works to display it, but I want to display it with html. `<img src="Flower.jpg">` doesn't do anything.

For my model User I'm also using Paperclip, which stores images in `public/system/users/avatars/000/000`, and `User.avatar_file_name` returns the absolute file path, which in this case is this: `/system/users/avatars/000/000/157/thumb/Flower.jpg?1248273956`. Inserting this path into src like this: `<img src="<%=@user.avatar_file_name%>">` works to display the image.

I found the absolute path of Flower.jpg in my rails console:

```
> helper.image_tag("Flower.jpg")
=> "<img alt=\"Flower\" src=\"/assets/Flower.jpg\" />
```

But then `<img src="/assets/Flower.jpg\">` doesn't display, even though `<img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/157/thumb/Flower.jpg?1248273956">` does. Why is that?

Comment: why is there a "\" at the end of the extension?

Comment: @Kritner I don't know. That's exactly the output that the rails console gave me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `image_tag` helper prepends the path to the standard images folder into the path to the file.  In my version of rails this is "/images/", so this

```
<%=image_tag("Flower.jpg")%>
```

is rendered out as

```
<img src="/images/Flower.jpg">
```

As with all resource paths like this, the actual file should be relative to your apps' public folder, ie

```
<RAILS ROOT>/public/images/Flower.jpg
```

In your version of rails it looks like the default path is `/app/assets/images/`, so this

```
<%=image_tag("Flower.jpg")%>
```

is rendered out as

```
<img src="/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg">
```

which points to this file:

```
<RAILS ROOT>/public/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg
```

If you do

```
<img src="Flower.jpg">
```

it will expect the file to be in `<RAILS ROOT>/public/Flower.jpg`, and obviously it's not there, so the img tag won't work.  If you want to write it out yourself, without using a helper, then give the path to the file from the `<RAILS ROOT/public` folder, ie

```
<img src="/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg">
```

BTW in your snippet of html you put `scr="` instead of `src="` which is going to break it even more.

Comment: `<img src="/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg">` doesn't do anything either. I don't think it's supposed to be pointing to `<RAILS ROOT>/public/app/assets/images/Flower.jpg` though. I do have a `public` folder, but it's separate from my `app` folder. `app` appears to be in root.

Comment: Where is the actual file, relative to your RAILS_ROOT folder?

Comment: It will need to be somewhere in your `RAILS_ROOT/public` folder, but bear in mind that when you predeploy Rails may copy files from `RAILS_ROOT/app/assets`  into `RAILS_ROOT/public`.

Comment: The path I have to follow to get to image is this: `RAILS_ROOT => app => assets => images => Flower.jpg`.

Comment: That's your problem then.  Your website can only link to resources in the public folder: you can't access a file in RAILS_ROOT/app on your web page.   Like i said, when you do an asset precompile rails will copy these from app/assets into public, and you'll need to link to the public location.

Comment: But `<%=image_tag("Flower.jpg")%>` works just fine! What can I do right now to render the images in Root/app? Or is it impossible with html?

Comment: It's not impossible, but having all of the site's publically accessable resources in the `public` folder is a convention which would be a lot of trouble for you to fight against.  I feel like a stuck record now, so i'm going to put this in caps in case you are deaf:  ALL OF YOUR SITE'S ASSETS (IMAGES, JAVASCRIPT, CSS, ETC) NEED TO BE IN THE PUBLIC FOLDER.  WHEN YOU DO AN ASSET PRECOMPILE, THEY ARE COPIED FROM YOUR APP/ASSETS FOLDER INTO PUBLIC.  Read this:  http://makandracards.com/makandra/8951-rails-asset-pipeline-why-things-break-in-production-and-what-precompilation-does-to-your-assets

Comment: Haha settle down. I'm just trying to find a way to use my images right now, before I precompile. I want to see what my view is _going_ to look like _after_ I precompile. Is there a way of linking to images in ROOT/app/assets, or do I have to precompile before I can see what my images look like?